# How to get rails admin working on production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Rails_admin works on my development server with port :3000, 
but not working on production server, responds 404 error!
How to get it working on production server ?

Thanks

Comment: Please, provide more information about the error, as like the relative return on the log file.

Comment: Only showing error 404, maybe I need to add some config to rails_admin .rb file for example?

Comment: You need to configure your http server

Comment: Can you explain more, how to configure server to serve images, javascripts and stylesheets from rails_admin assets git gem?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue? Facing the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried running the following?:

```
$ rake rails_admin:copy_assets
```

Spotted this little bit in the [GitHub ReadMe](https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/#readme):

> When running RailsAdmin in production the images, stylesheets,
>   and javascript assets may return 404
>   not found error's depending on your
>   servers static assets configuration.
>   To prevent this issue you can copy
>   assets directly into your application
>   by running:
>
> $ rake rails_admin:copy_assets

Comment: I get a "Don't know how to build task 'rails_admin:copy_assets'" error

Comment: This is 5 years old.

Answer (score -3):

I had to do a `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake db:reset`, then it worked. Don't know whether it was a user session issue (no privileges?) or something else.

Be careful though not to execute the command above if you have "real" data in your database!